# Handling shared jvm properties & arguments in maven child porjects

Tags: maven, pom.xml, reusability

We have 6 child modules, and all of them have same values for  & . But slight addition in jvmArguments for few modules.
I want to extract this out into a common place either parent pom or a property file.

what i have done is

```html
<mymodule-jvmArguments>long list of props</mymodule-jvmArguments>
```

in parent pom and use this property in child modules.
so whereever there is additional propeties, it would be like

```html
                    <jvmArguments>
                        additional properties
                        ${mymodule-jvmArguments}
                    </jvmArguments>
```

Is this something advisable? Please suggest if there is a better means to handle shared properties. Thanks in advance

child pom sample properties

```html
<jvmArguments>
                        -DmyAppp1.host=${local.base.url}:${myAppp1.port}
                        -DmyAppp2.host=${local.base.url}:${myAppp2.port}
-DSENSITIVE_CONFIG_PATH1=${project.parent.parent.basedir}/foo1/bar1
                        
-DSENSITIVE_CONFIG_PATH1=${project.parent.parent.basedir}/foo1/bar1
                        
-DDSENSITIVE_CONFIG_PATH3=${project.parent.parent.basedir}/foo3/bar3
                        
-DDSENSITIVE_CONFIG_PATH4=${project.parent.parent.basedir}/foo4/bar4
                        
-DCOMMON_SENSITIVE_PATH=${project.parent.parent.basedir}/foo/common
                    </jvmArguments>
```

Comment: Why do you have jvm arguments in your build configuration for different modules? What kind of properties/jvm arguments you have to use? Running the build or running the test?

Comment: few of the sensitive information which changes based on environment that we deploy. for example mongo password. This changes for prod and non prod

Comment: This should never being necessary for running the build. Such things like credentials should always giving from the running environment and never put into the artifact...Apart from that you can please add your pom file so we can take a look.

Comment: @khmarbaise we arent putting the sensitive information, rather the file paths are provided as jvm args here.

Comment: In the end it does not matter violates [12-Factor principle](https://12factor.net/). Furthermore you didn't show the pom files?

Comment: Not sure i am allowed to share the entire pom config, it would violate company policy. Anything particular you are after in this. I understand this config is not something in par with the rules you mentioned. Can u suggest the right way. I hope my problem statement is clear

Comment: Give 2-3 example with dummy values how you have it configured in your current poms...

Comment: updated in the Question

Comment: Is this application a spring boot application? debug configuration does not make sense cause debugging can be done in the IDE or via remote debugging?? All these paths I would put into a properties file which is loaded on the environment externally and not put into the app? SSL configuration? from inside a jar/war? does not make sense?

Comment: ok i guess we are deviating from the main topic. simple question, how do we manage jvm args across multimodule mvm project.